# KeyValuePair export to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I trying to export my data to excel file , and i building object and pass it to export, i want to make check before building complete object but it failed

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(int roleId, int? levelId)
        {
            var moduleItems = db.C_UserItems
                .Include(x => x.S_Registration)
                .Where(x => x.RoleId == roleId);

            if (levelId != null)
                moduleItems = moduleItems.Where(x => x.S_Registration.LevelId == levelId);

            List<object> objList = new List<object>();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in moduleItems)
            {
                i++;

                List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> obj = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
                obj.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Num", i));
                obj.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Name", item.Name));
                obj.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Email", item.Email));

                if (roleId == 5)
                {
                    obj.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Phone", item.Phone));
                    obj.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("CellPhone", item.CellPhone));
                }

                objList.Add(obj);
            }

            SaveToExcel(objList);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = roleId, levelId = levelId });
        }
```

and this is my export method

```
protected void SaveToExcel(List<object> objList)
            {
                //Save result as excel file
                HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
                // first let's clean up the response.object
                response.Clear();
                // set the response mime type for excel
                response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"Alaglan.xls\"");
                response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
                response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());

                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                {
                    using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                    {
                        // instantiate a datagrid
                        GridView dg = new GridView();

                        dg.DataSource = objList;
                        dg.DataBind();
                        dg.RenderControl(htw);
                        response.Write(sw.ToString());
                        response.End();
                    }
                }
            }
```

the result appears as count, capacity for each row , i tried another way before to build this object and it works good but its so hard for building big data ,

```
if (roleId == 4)
                {
                    objList.Add(new
                    {
                        m = i,
                        name = item.Name,
                        email = item.Email
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    objList.Add(new
                    {
                        m = i,
                        name = item.Name,
                        email = item.Email,
                        identity = item.S_Registration.Identification
                    });
                }
```

anyone can help me please for best way to build object with some check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, this seems wrong to me:

```
obj.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Name", item.Phone));
obj.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Email", item.CellPhone));
```

should be `Phone` and `CellPhone` instead of `Name` and `Email`:

```
obj.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Phone", item.Phone));
obj.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("CellPhone", item.CellPhone));
```

Second, I think you cannot generate `GridView` from your stucture that uses `KeyValuePair` out of the box.

However, I would rewrite the code to use `DataTable` instead of anonymous objects and key/value pairs and bind that `DataTable` to `GridView`.
It offers more flexibility than anonymous objects and does not have a problem with binding that `KeyValuePair` have.

For example:

```
// Create data table to be filled
var DT = new DataTable();
DT.Columns.Add("Num", typeof(int));
DT.Columns.Add("Name");
DT.Columns.Add("Phone");
DT.Columns.Add("CellPhone");

...

int i = 0;
foreach (var item in moduleItems)
{
    i++;

    DataRow Row = DT.NewRow();
    Row["Num"] = i;
    Row["Name"] = item.Name;
    Row["Email"] = item.Email;

    if (roleId == 5)
    {
        Row["Phone"] = item.Phone;
        Row["CellPhone"] = item.CellPhone;
    }

    DT.Rows.Add(Row);
}

...

// instantiate a datagrid
GridView dg = new GridView();

dg.DataSource = DT.DefaultView;
dg.DataBind();
dg.RenderControl(htw);
response.Write(sw.ToString());
response.End();
```

Comment: I have more than 150 column to export on each row , and some of this columns i must check before render it , so i searching for a solution help me to do that , the last code i added works perfect but i cant check on properties easily, i must retype whole columns, so i tried to use keyvaluepairs but it didnt work correct

Comment: Then, switch to `DataTable` as I have said in updated answer.
See, the `DataTable` also offers easy access to rows/values (in contrast to anonymous objects).

Comment: i'm so sorry, but can you explain your answer with little bit of code to understand this, thanks in advance